# HTTP 403 Error while accessing web service

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services

Im trying to access a web service from a remote computer. I managed to access the web service from the browser. But Im getting HTTP 403 when I try to call the web service from the application.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [403](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4) response indicates that the host or software you're connecting with isn't allowed to access the web service. Reasons for this might be:

- The remote host you are is being blocked by a firewall
- You've reached the limit of calls to the web service and they are blocking any further connections
- You are sending credentials for authentication but the account is banned/disabled
- The user-agent or some other header in your request is causing the service to reject the connection. Perhaps a missing header?

Comment: I have similar problem, the wired thing is.. when running from nunit application, the service is fine, when running from windows services, i get 403. !!

Comment: I have same problem and using .net webservice & IIS 7.5 to get data. Getting error uncertain not always. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The Web server thinks that the HTTP data stream sent by the client was correct, but access to the resource identified by the URL is forbidden for some reason.Check the firewall settings.This should help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where the browser could access an url and my simple java call got a 403 error. I got it working by adding http header information to the request. I copied what the browser send.